# Using REGEX in if-elsif-else condition

Tags: c#, asp.net, regex

i want to only test/ntest then output is test test but so only replace /n to one white space but some case /r/n also replace but can'y replace to that syatax only replace between two word so i return this regex syntax but not working.

```
string input = "/r/ntest/ntest/n/r"
input = Regex.Replace(input, ".\n.", " ");
```

Comment: string input = "\r\ntest\ntest\n\r";
input = Regex.Replace(input, ".\n.", " ");

Comment: 1) Your code contains a syntax issue. 2) What do you mean/are up to?

Answer (score 0):

I think you'll have to provide the condition, that you want a non \r character to exist before the \n, to the Regex - but you'll have to add the non \r character found into the replacement string or it'll be cut out:

```
Regex.Replace(input, @"(?<before>[^\r])\n", m => m.Groups["before"].Value + " ");
```

**(?<before>...)** defines a named group you can access later

**[^\r]** defines that a character that is NOT \r exists here

**m => m...** is a Lambda expression where m in this case is a **Match** instance

Alternatively in that specific case you can also mess around with a simple replace:

```
input = input.Replace("\r\n", "\r").Replace('\n', ' ').Replace("\r", "\r\n");
```

Comment: Your regex can be written as `Regex.Replace(input, @"(?<!\r)\n", " ")`.